# What is the harm in ignoring warning in make?

Tags: compilation, makefile, cross-compiling

I want to ask if there is any harm in ignoring this kind of warning by using

```
make -i
```

instead of

```
make
```

after recieving this warning:

```
    utils.o: In function `ast_gethostbyname':
/home/mohessaid/asterisk-1.4.44/main/utils.c:224: warning: gethostbyname_r is obsolescent, use getnameinfo() instead.
```

Comment: of course the process completed with success after using the -i option and this warning occur in the last task in the compilation process. all the *.o files generated correctly but the linker seems to have a problem with this line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it's a good idea to run compilation with all warnings on, to easier be able to track down errors either in the build process or at runtime. This is extremely useful for developers, but it can also be useful for end users.

As an example, I had to compile a major piece of software, and only when I tried to use it it complained that SSL was not enabled. Looking back at the compilation output it printed a big warning saying that several *optional* dependencies were not configured, so their related functionality would not be enabled. After installing the necessary SSL development package `make` no longer printed the warning for that specific dependency and I could be sure that the functionality would work.

As for `-i` *specifically*, it says in the `man` page that is to "Ignore all **errors** in commands executed to remake files" (my emphasis). That does *not* sound like a good idea, and since `make` *quits* when it encounters an error it doesn't seem likely that you'll get a useful result out of the process, `-i` or no `-i`.